# News site crawling doesn't work?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, jupyter-notebook

Hello I'm a python newbie, sorry to be asking such a specific question when I don't know what is going wrong..

I'm trying to crawl news articles from a korean new site.
When i run this code

```
    import sys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.parse import quote

    target_url_b4_pn="http://news.donga.com/search?p="
    target_url_b4_keyword='&query='

target_url_rest="&check_news1&more=1&sorting1&search_date1&v1=&v2=&range=1"



    def get_text(URL, output_file):
        source_code_from_URL=urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code_from_URL, 'lxml', from_encoding='UTF-8')
        content_of_article=soup.select('div.article')
        for item in content_of_article:
            string_item=str(item.find_all(text=True))
            output_file.write(string_item)

    def get_link_from_news_title(page_num, URL, output_file):
        for i in range(page_num):
            current_page_num=1+i*15
            position=URL.index('=')
                    URL_with_page_num=URL[:position+1]+str(current_page_num)+URL[position+1:]
            source_code_from_URL=urllib.request.urlopen(URL_with_page_num)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code_from_URL, 'lxml',from_encoding='UTF-8')

            for title in soup.find_all('p','tit'):
                title_link=title.select('a')
                article_URL=title_link[0]['href']
                get_text(article_URL, output_file)

    def main():
        keyword="노무현"
        page_num=1
        output_file_name="output.txt"
        target_url=target_url_b4_pn+target_url_b4_keyword+quote(keyword)+target_url_rest
        output_file=open(output_file_name, "w", -1, "utf-8")
        get_link_from_news_title(page_num, target_url, output_file)
        output_file.close()


    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
    print(target_url)
    print(11111)
```

## The jupyter notebook doesn't respond to the input, doesnt even spit out any simple command at the bottom(doesn't print anything)

Think the code is freezing it somehow, please tell me where it might be going wrong?

[the picture where it's not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXH4R.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. The first line of your `get_text` function, `urllib.request.urlopen(URL)` means you open the url, but just like you open a file, you have to `read` it.
   So add a `read()` after it.
   `urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()` otherwise beautifulsoup will not recognize it.
2. and in your css selector `soup.select('div.article')`, there is no such element in the page, I guess what you want is `soup.select('div.article_txt')`, it match the paragraph of the article.
3. your `print(target_url)` should move into your `main` function, for `target_url` only defined in `main`.

## Code

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote

target_url_b4_pn="http://news.donga.com/search?p="
target_url_b4_keyword='&query='

target_url_rest="&check_news1&more=1&sorting1&search_date1&v1=&v2=&range=1"



def get_text(URL, output_file):
    source_code_from_URL=urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code_from_URL, 'lxml', from_encoding='UTF-8')
    # change your css selector so it match some element
    content_of_article=soup.select('div.article_txt')
    for item in content_of_article:
        string_item=item.find_all(text=True)
        #write string to file
        output_file.write(" ".join(string_item))

def get_link_from_news_title(page_num, URL, output_file):
    for i in range(page_num):
        current_page_num=1+i*15
        position=URL.index('=')
        URL_with_page_num=URL[:position+1]+str(current_page_num)+URL[position+1:]
        source_code_from_URL=urllib.request.urlopen(URL_with_page_num)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code_from_URL, 'lxml',from_encoding='UTF-8')

        for title in soup.find_all('p','tit'):
            title_link=title.select('a')
            article_URL=title_link[0]['href']
            get_text(article_URL, output_file)

def main():
    keyword="노무현"
    page_num=1
    output_file_name="output.txt"
    target_url=target_url_b4_pn+target_url_b4_keyword+quote(keyword)+target_url_rest
    # move `target_url` here
    print(target_url)

    output_file=open(output_file_name, "w", -1, "utf-8")
    get_link_from_news_title(page_num, target_url, output_file)
    output_file.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
    print(11111)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! its so kind of you! I changed the code but its still not spitting out the result within an hour... It'll be nice if you could make any suggestion to improve it.

Comment: The result `output.txt` will be in your current directory, do you check that file?